# Cannot convert byte to int in Golang

Tags: go, type-conversion, byte

This is strange but I cannot convert byte value into int.

Here is the code:

```
fmt.Println("numMsgsByte is:", numMsgsByte)
numMsgsStr := string(numMsgsByte)
fmt.Println("numMsgsStr is:", numMsgsStr)
numMsgs, err = strconv.Atoi(numMsgsStr)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("error in msg conversion", err)
    return 0
}
```

The terminal print out:

```
numMsgsByte is: [5]
numMsgsStr is: 
counter.go:51: error in msg conversion strconv.Atoi: parsing "\x05": invalid syntax
```

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: This seems like a problem with the way you're using Redis; the Redis driver should be able to give you an `int` directly. Perhaps if you showed the code where you're getting the value from Redis, the entirety of the existing question would become moot.

Comment: @Adrian I'm getting byte from redigo redis driver like this: `numMsgsByte, err := redis.Bytes(conn.Do("GET", key))`

Comment: Why are you using `redis.Bytes` if you want an integer back? Why not use `redis.Int`? Have you looked at [the redigo documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis)?

Comment: Yes, I looked at that and corrected the issue with redis. It is irrelevant. Just want to know how to covert a byte array to int.

Comment: Using the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

`numMsgByte` is not a byte, it is a `[]byte`, which contains 5 (not "5"). When you convert it to string using `string(numMsgByte)`, you get a string "\x5".

What you need is: `int(numMsgType[0])`

Comment: Great, you mean `int(numMsgsByte[0])`.  What if the byte contains several digits, like `542`? Does this still work?

Comment: Realize that what you get back is an array, and it may contain multiple values. Are you going to interpret that as separate values, or higher (lower) bits of a single number?

Comment: I'm going to interpret `numMsgByte` as a single integer, no matter the number of digits in the  byte array. So how can I acheive that?

Comment: That is not clear. Are you going to throw away the rest of the bytes? Or is that big-endian or little-endian integer?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get an integer out of Redis using redigo would be to just use `redis.Int` in the first place, instead of using `redis.Bytes` and trying to convert the result to an `int` yourself.

In general though, to convert an arbitrary byte array to the integer it represents, you would use the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package. You'll need to know some key details about the byte array though:

- Does it represent a signed or unsigned value?
- Of what width? 32 bit? 64 bit?
- Of what byte order? Big-endian? Little-endian?
- Are you sure it's represented as an integer, not e.g. a float, or a string representation of a number?

To quote the example from the docs:

```
b := []byte{0xe8, 0x03, 0xd0, 0x07}
x1 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(b[0:])
x2 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(b[2:])
fmt.Printf("%#04x %#04x\n", x1, x2)
```